# does function name affect to transaction speed?

Tags: solidity, transactions

I know that if I attach many 0s to contract address, it saves gas fee.
But I am curious if it also affects to the speed.
for example, if I made function name to 0x00000000, then that function process faster?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Saving GAS and transaction processing speed are not related concepts.

GAS is a made-up unit of measure of an operation cost. While executing the sequence of operations in a smart contract, the EVM keeps track of the cost of each operation in GAS units.

To use a standard for determining the cost of the execution regardless of SW and HW, GAS is used to assign a fixed cost to each operation so that an operation that requires more resources (i.e., `BALANCE` = 100 GAS) costs more than less resource intensive operation (i.e., `ADD` = 3 GAS).

See the [evm.codes website](https://www.evm.codes/) for more details and a useful playground.

The speed to execute an operation depends on the specific implementation of the EVM and the HW that runs the EVM.

This is why, for example, some clients can execute more MGAS/second than others. And that performance can be improved with hard work and time (see Besu, for example, improving from less than ~90 MGAS/s for v21.7 to ~400 MGAS/s of v23.10). Here is [the full analysis](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/display/BESU/2024+-+Besu+Performance+Improvements+since+the+Merge).

Real-world GAS optimization is a complex topic; its applicability can be case by case, and it usually comes at the cost of readability and clarity of the code. Finally, you can apply many techniques before considering very minimal differences, like the presence of zeros in the transaction payload or the contract code.

I suggest concentrating on making things work first and only after that, thinking about GAS optimization, and only if needed (i.e., if the gain is 1%, but you make your code more complex and hard to understand, don't optimize).

Side note.

The speed of executing the transaction by a client is unrelated to the finality time (the time to get a transaction included in the ledger).

Multiple factors determine that type of speed, but the major impact is the total fees in ether users want to pay for that transaction.

The total fees are `TOTAL GAS` (determined by the EVM) * `GAS PRICE` (in ether per each unit of GAS, decided by the sender of the transaction) = `TOTAL FEES` paid to the validator. Validator/block producers will likely give priority to transactions where the `TOTAL FEES` are bigger. Those are the transactions that are actually executed and finalized *faster*.